# Drawing with turtle(python) using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I'm running the latest PyCharm Pro version and trying to run the below code from a scratch file but it doesn't seem to work

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() 
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.forward(150)  
alex.left(90) 
alex.forward(75)
```

By not working I mean, no window is popping out however I do see in the output saying

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any idea

1. If it can be done via PyCharm
2. What am I missing in terms of configuration

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem like so:

```
def main():
    wn = turtle.Screen()  # creates a graphics window
    alex = turtle.Turtle()  # create a turtle named alex
    alex.forward(150)  # tell alex to move forward by 150 units
    alex.left(90)  # turn by 90 degrees
    alex.forward(75)  # complete the second side of a rectangle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The only downside is that it does close the canvas once it finished.

Comment: None of the changes here should be relevant to the error that was actually reported.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out the solution is in the "turtle" module.

You want to end with

turtle.done()

or

turtle.exitonclick()

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

By "no window is popping out" means that the program is executing and then directly closing. To fix it you have to loop the program as follows:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() 
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.forward(150)  
alex.left(90) 
alex.forward(75)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Allan Anderson says, easiest way I found (as I don't use main that often):

```
turtle.exitonclick()
```

As the last line of code forces the Graphics Window to stay open until it is clicked.

Comment: If someone already gave the answer, why repeat it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    import turtle
    wn = turtle.Screen()  # creates a graphics window
    alex = turtle.Turtle()  # create a turtle named alex
    alex.forward(150)  # tell alex to move forward by 150 units
    alex.left(90)  # turn by 90 degrees
    alex.forward(75)  # complete the second side of a rectangle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

    input("Press RETURN to close.  ")
```

The last line will hold display till RETURN key is not pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code. You are missing the function which keep the screen alive until it is closed by the user. **exitonclick()** Method helps to keep screen alive.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()    
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.forward(150)      
alex.left(90)     
alex.forward(75)    
wn.exitonclick()
```